# have some issue in my script but not able to debug oit

Tags: javascript, django

i am implementing the auto complete search bar in my django project  and below is my script for showing the suggestion the renderList function is not working. render result is working.
i want showing data on front end for that my renderList function need to work but somehow it is not working.becz there is the format in which the data will be displayed.

```
                        <div class="header-right">
                        <form action="{% url 'Search' %}">
                       <div id="mobile-autocomplete" class="autocomplete">
                            <input class="autocomplete-input" name="query" 
                             placeholder="Search" />
                            <ul class="autocomplete-result-list autocomplete-result- 
                        list-mobile" style="padding: 10px; max-height:842px;"></ul><hr>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <script>
                        new Autocomplete('#mobile-autocomplete', {
                            search: input => {
                              const url = `{% url 'search_address'%}?query=${input}`;
                              return new Promise(resolve => {
                                fetch(url)
                                  .then(response => response.json())
                                  .then(data => {
                                    resolve(data.data || []);
                                  })
                                  .catch(error => {
                                    console.error('Error fetching autocomplete 
                                    results:', error);
                                    resolve([]);
                                  });
                              });
                            },
                            onSubmit: result => {
                              const words = result.split(' ');
                              const query = words.join(' ');
                              window.location.assign(`/Search?query=${query}`);
                            },
                            renderResult: (result, props) => {
                              console.log('Rendering result:', result);
                              const { name, image, url } = result;
                              const item = document.createElement('div');
                              item.classList.add('autocomplete-item');
                          
                              const imageContainer = document.createElement('div');
                              imageContainer.classList.add('autocomplete-image');
                              const img = document.createElement('img');
                              img.src = image;
                              img.alt = name;
                              imageContainer.appendChild(img);
                          
                              const nameContainer = document.createElement('div');
                              nameContainer.classList.add('autocomplete-name');
                              const link = document.createElement('a');
                              link.href = url;
                              link.textContent = name;
                              nameContainer.appendChild(link);
                          
                              item.appendChild(imageContainer);
                              item.appendChild(nameContainer);
                          
                              return item;
                            },
                            renderList: (data, props) => {
                              console.log('Rendering list:', data);
                              const ul = document.createElement('ul');
                              ul.classList.add('autocomplete-result-list', 
                              'autocomplete-result-list-mobile');
                          
                              if (data.length > 0) {
                                const popularSuggestions = data.slice(0, 5);
                                const otherSuggestions = data.slice(5);
                          
                                if (popularSuggestions.length > 0) {
                                  const popularTitle = document.createElement('div');
                                  popularTitle.classList.add('autocomplete-section- 
                                  title');
                                  popularTitle.textContent = 'POPULAR SUGGESTION';
                          
                                  ul.appendChild(popularTitle);
                          
                                  for (const suggestion of popularSuggestions) {
                                    const item = props.renderResult(suggestion, props);
                                    ul.appendChild(item);
                                  }
                          
                                  const popularLine = document.createElement('hr');
                                  ul.appendChild(popularLine);
                                }
                          
                                if (otherSuggestions.length > 0) {
                                  const productsTitle = document.createElement('div');
                                  productsTitle.classList.add('autocomplete-section- 
                                  title');
                                  productsTitle.textContent = 'PRODUCTS';
                          
                                  ul.appendChild(productsTitle);
                          
                                  const relevantSuggestion = otherSuggestions[0];
                                  const relevantItem = 
                                  props.renderResult(relevantSuggestion, props);
                                  ul.appendChild(relevantItem);
                                }
                              }
                          
                              return ul;
                            }
                          });
                          
                          
                    </script>
                    
                    
                </div>
```